# flutter change image onPressed

Tags: flutter

I'am trying to change an icon image onPressed here is my code. and based on the selected value before and after onPressed it should be working

[image]

Thanks for your help.

```
IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            print(selected);
                                            setState(() {
                                              selected = true;
                                            });
                                            print(selected);
                                          },
                                          icon: CircleAvatar(
                                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                                'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/zrvgBfLZl94O6yJ_BlEInCIopvsokkrrrpBmVcByKwLSmacEV6B1P-SJA6eKP84ibOjFpA=s26'),
                                            child: selected == false
                                                ? Image.asset(
                                                    'assets/images/Icon ionic-ios-heart-empty.png')
                                                : Image.asset(
                                                    'assets/images/Icon ionic-ios-heart.png'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `selected` boolean is defined outside the `Widget build` method. Because it seems that it's not changing.
Also try changing `selected =true` => `selected=!selected`.

If the print statement is working, then it's most likely that you defined `selected` under `Widget build`.

Don't do this:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  bool selected =false;

  return IconButton(...etc
```

Do this:

```
bool selected =false;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return IconButton(...etc
```